# How To Update Existing Profile Django Model Form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to allow users to be able to create and edit their profiles once they have registered. I am using a model form. What I need to do is have the employer model field be filled with the current user.

**Here is my view:**

```
def update_profile(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        edit_profile_form=EditProfileForm(request.POST)
        if edit_profile_form.is_valid():
            editprofile = edit_profile_form.save(commit=False)
            editprofile.employer = request.user.get_profile()
            editprofile.save()
    edit_profile_form = EditProfileForm()
    context = {'edit_profile_form':edit_profile_form,}
    return render(request, 'pandaboard/editprofile.html', context)
```

**Here is my model:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    employer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_description = models.TextField()
    company_website = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

**Here is my Model Form**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from pandaboard.models import JobPost, Profile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class EditProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['company_name','company_description','company_website','contact_email','contact_name']
```

Comment: Is `EditProfileForm` a ModelForm for Profile? Please post your form class.

Comment: Ok I added my model form

Comment: When updating a model, typically you will hand your model form an instance of the model to pre-populate the form with existing data from the model. Is that what you're needing to do? or do you not want to do that, and instead need to inject the current user into the form?

Comment: I will actually be needing to do both. But this form is for updating a model that already exists.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll post an example of how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update an object from edit form in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673985/how-to-update-an-object-from-edit-form-in-django)

Answer (score 10):

To hydrate your form with values from your existing model instance, you need to use the `instance` argument on the model form:

```
def update_profile(request, username):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    edit_profile_form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None,
        current_user=request.user, instance=profile)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if edit_profile_form.is_valid():
            editprofile.save()

    context = {'edit_profile_form': edit_profile_form}
    return render(request, 'pandaboard/editprofile.html', context)
```

To inject the current request.user, you can override the `__init__` of `EditProfileForm`, passing in an extra keyword argument (or arg, it doesn't really matter), and the popping it out of the kwargs before calling super so you aren't passing the ModelForm a keyword argument it isn't expecting:

```
class EditProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        current_user = kwargs.pop('current_user')
        super(EditProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['employer'] = current_user
```

Now you don't have to pass `commit=False` and manually set the value of `employer` in the view.

Comment: I get the following error: 

Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: company_description, company_name, company_website, contact_email, contact_name, employer, id, jobpost    Do I need to have the employer field actually called user?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not seeing a reason why your code won't work, but I did notice that you have .pyc files checked into Git. You'll want to exclude those in your .gitignore. Try clearing out all of the .pyc files and restarting the built-in server.