# How to partially update an object when using modelForm in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to let users to add/update caption of their already updated photos without changing any other field of the photo.

Here is the model:

```
class UserPic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    picfile = ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to= get_uplaod_file_name, sizes=((648,648),(200,200),(1200,1200)))
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200 , blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    liked_by= models.ForeignKey(Liker, blank=True)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_pirate', None, {'user': self.account.user})    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.picfile.name)
```

views.py

```
def edit_photo(request, pic_id):
    pic = UserPic.objects.get(id=pic_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':        
         if pic.user== request.user:
            picform = CaptionForm(request.POST)
            if picform.is_valid():
                edform = picform.save(commit=False)
                edform.caption = request.POST['caption']
                edform.save()
                message = "caption is uploaded" 


    else:
        edform = CaptionForm() 

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['pic'] = pic
    args['pic_id'] = pic_id
    #args['form'] = edform

    return render_to_response('userpics/photo.html', args,    
                              context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

photo.html

```
<div class="caption">
        <form action="{% url "userpics.views.edit_photo" pic.id %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}            
        {{form.as_ul}}           
        <input type="submit" value="SEND">
        </form>
```

forms.py:

```
class CaptionForm(forms.ModelForm):    
        class Meta:
                model= UserPic
                fields = ('caption',)
```

However when I post the form, django still complain that:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /pics/edit/26
"'caption'"
```

I really got confused as I could not find any resources to deal with this particular problem. So appreciate your hints.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update an object from edit form in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673985/how-to-update-an-object-from-edit-form-in-django)

Comment: See the answer at the linked question for most of how to do this - you want to pass the `UserPic` instance you're editing to the form constructor as the `instance` argument, then just save the form rather than reading from `request.POST` directly. I don't like the `request.POST or None` pattern at the linked answer, I'd stick with your more conventional `if request.method == 'POST'` approach.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper when I use just picform.save(), I get 'userpics_userpic.liked_by_id may not be NULL', that is django expects to receive values for other fields. That's why I tried to get caption directly from POST.

Comment: That shouldn't happen if you use the `instance` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to solved the problem like this:

photo.html

```
    <form action="{% url "userpics.views.edit_photo" pic.id %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="caption" value="{{pic.caption}}">
        <input type="submit" value="SEND">
    </form>
```

views.py

```
def edit_photo(request, pic_id):
    pic = UserPic.objects.get(id=pic_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':        
         if pic.user== request.user:
            picform = CaptionForm(request.POST)             
            if picform.is_valid():
                pic.caption = request.POST['caption']
                pic.save()
                message = "caption is uploaded" 

    else:
        edform = CaptionForm(instance=pic) 

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['pic'] = pic
    args['pic_id'] = pic_id

    return render_to_response('userpics/photo.html', args,    
                              context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```