# If statement always returning True

Tags: python, django, if-statement

for my django project I have a page which allows a user to edit their listing, for this I am adding a check that ensures the person opening the page is the owner of the listing. However the if statement I have put in always returns true no matter what, even if I change what it is checking to a totally unrelated object. I even changed it from != to == and it always returned true, does anyone know what is going on here?

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='login')
def editlisting(request, pk):

    post = JobListing.objects.get(pk=pk)

    print(type(request.user))
    print(type(post.user))

    if request.user != post.user:
        print("THIS WORKS") #This is for debugging
        print(request.user) #This is for debugging
        print(post.user) #This is for debugging
        return redirect("index")

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = JobListingForm(request.POST, instance=post)

        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = request.user
            profile.save()
            return redirect('index')

    else:
        form = JobListingForm(instance=post)

    context = {
        "form": form
    }

    return render(request, "editlisting.html", context)
```

Any help appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is what is in the console-
http://puu.sh/kBuuX/30501a9407.png

Also here is my model code

```
class JobListing(models.Model):

    region_choice = (
        ('1', 'Auckland'),
        ('2', 'Wellington'),
        ('3', 'Christchurch')
    )
    industry_choice = (
        ('1', 'Accounting'),
        ('2', 'Agriculture, fishing & forestry'),
        ('3', 'Automotive'),
        ('4', 'Banking, finance & insurance'),
        ('5', 'Construction & Architecture'),
        ('6', 'Customer service'),
    )
    employment_type_choice = (
        ('1', 'Full Time'),
        ('2', 'Part Time'),
        ('3', 'One-off'),
        ('4', 'Other')
    )

    user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pay_rate = models.FloatField()
    employment_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=employment_type_choice)
    job_description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    business_address_region = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=region_choice)
    business_address_suburb = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    business_industry = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=industry_choice)
    contact_method = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active_listing = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Job Listing'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.business_name
```

Comment: And what does it print in your "debugging"?

Comment: Move the print statements before the test, and add `print(type(request.user)); print(type(post.user))` to make sure you're comparing comparable objects.

Comment: Also, try using .pk, most simple comparison when you are expecting two items from the same table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and **dirty** fix:

```
if str(request.user) != str(post.user):
```

In your debugging, you see the same string, because the `print` function calls the `str` function implicitly (it can only ptrint strings). But you actually try to compare an object (request.user) with a strin (post.user), which gives unexpected results.

---

**Durable** fix:

In your `JobListing` model, the field `user` should be a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) (and not a CharField).

You can then compare the `pk` (primary key) attribute of request.user and post.user (as suggested by @Beltiras).

Comment: Initially I had the user field as a onetoone however I had to change that as it would not allow users to have multiple listings because the username needs to be unique. Any idea on how I could solve that?

Comment: I just realized why I was having the problem with it not being unique, it is because when I am saving the updated form it is not updating the old one it is trying to make a new one and leave the old one the same. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673985/how-to-update-an-object-from-edit-form-in-django). If you are still not able to solve your problem, please open another question.

Comment: I know the op has already accepted but can I suggest your dirty fix becomes `if request.user.get_username() != post.user:`? As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_username) - ". Since the User model can be swapped out, you should use this method instead of referencing the username attribute directly." The durable fix is *greatly* preferred still

Comment: I prefer leaving my post *as is* and let the people directly read your comment (since it's regarding an unrecommended solution)

Answer (score -3):

I don't know your model, but I guess that `JobListing.user` is a ForeignKey to a User. In this case you are comparing the User instance against a string, which will different in any case. Maybe you need something like:

```
if request.user != post.user.username:
```

Check your model for the right attribute name.

Comment: If it really is an fk then the op isn't comparing a user against a string, it would be a user against a user, and doesn't explain why the op's switching of the boolean operator still returns the same value

Comment: Well, we would be more enlightened with the model.

Comment: I think we need an answer to oliverpool's comment at least before this is answerable. `request.user` is always a User instance in django by default also.

Comment: I have added my model