# Django - update database rows

Tags: python, django, database, forms

I've just begun to learning django and im stucked with one problem. I dont know how to **update**  database rows(fields).  AT THE MOMENT MY DATABASE TABLE IS ADDING EXTRA INFORMATION WHEN I CALL form_valid.

And yes , i read this : [How to update an object from edit form in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673985/how-to-update-an-object-from-edit-form-in-django)

But it doesnt work for me. It is still adding more information everytime .

**View.py**

```
    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        print 'heeee'
        students = Student.objects.all()
        studies = Student_in_Subgroup.objects.all()
        subgroups = Subgroup.objects.all()

        lists = self.request.POST.getlist('studs[]')

        sum = 0
        for student in students:
            for l in lists:
                if student.id == int(l):
                    for studie in studies:
                        if studie.student_Id.id == student.id:
                            for subgroup in subgroups:
                                if studie.subgroup_Id.id == subgroup.id:
                                    print student.id
                                    studentId = student.id
                                    key = subgroup.student_group_id
                                    sum = sum + 1
                                    if subgroup.number == None:
                                        continue
                                    subgroupId = studie.subgroup_Id.id
        if (self.request.POST.get('act1')=='add'):
            #problem sowhere here I THINK
            instance = get_object_or_404(Subgroup, id=subgroupId)
            form = ApplicationFormaFull1(self.request.POST or None, instance=instance)
            form.save()
            #problem sowhere here I THINK
            xxx=form['sub']
            xxx.student_group = StudentGroup.objects.get(id=key)
            xxx.number = self.request.POST.get('act2')
            xxx.type = self.request.POST.get('act3')
            xxx.stundent_count = sum
            xxx.save()
            yyy=form['stud_sub']
            yyy.subgroup_Id = Subgroup.objects.get(id=subgroupId)
            yyy.student_Id = Student.objects.get(id=studentId)
            yyy.save()
        else:
            print('no')
        return super(IndexView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**Form.py**

```
class FormSubgroup(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Subgroup
        exclude = ['student_group','number','type','student_count']

class FormStudent_in_Subgroup(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Student_in_Subgroup
        exclude = ['subgroup_Id','student_Id']

class ApplicationFormaFull1(MultiModelForm):
    form_classes = {
        'sub': FormSubgroup,
        'stud_sub': FormStudent_in_Subgroup
    }
```

Maybe someone knows a solution

Comment: You need to let us know what do you mean by "extra information".

Comment: For example i want to add a new row (student name , surname....)

Answer (score -1):

To edit information in your model, you use .update. For example Student.objects.filter(id=studentId).update(fieldname = newvalue)

Comment: Shang Wang, I thought the poster meant adding rows to the model (which happens when you use a .save) as opposed to editing existing information in fields (which happens when you use .update). The poster indicated a desire to update but is using the .save.

Comment: ITS WORKING , the data is updating, however it is also creates a new row (with null values)... :/ http://pastebin.com/uK3mWi1F