# django update forms, who pass object id?

Tags: django, forms, object, signing

I've tried to create a simple `ModelForm`, and I notice that even if I pass an instance for update like that

```
mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
MyModelForm(instance=mymodel)
```

django does not create an hidden field or include in some way the pk of the object in the template. So I need to pass this by myself? 
I prefer not passing the my id's like 1,2,3.. to the templates, so I would prefer passing something like uuid, or using `signing.dumps(object_id)`, and then `signing.loads(object_id)`, from django signing library.
So if I want to include this id in my template with the form POST data, 
I didn't understand who is exactly responsible for the retrieve of that id - Is that the view or the form itself? 
By view I mean to the built-ins `FormView`, or `UpdateView`, how these views find the object id? Assume to store the output of `signing.dumps(object_id)` in a hidden field

Comment: Why would you need to pass it in the form? You already have it in the view.

Comment: well the form generate all the fields. And this field( signed id, or uuid) is an hidden field (supposed to be)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update an object from edit form in Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673985/how-to-update-an-object-from-edit-form-in-django)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time you are in the template the form construction has completed.  You can try accessing form.instance.id if its modelForm.

However, most likely you do not need the pk in the template, do you ? You can also inject a hidden form field with the instance pk value if you like. Why do you need the pk in the template ?

If you want to redirect to another page from the POST data you will have access to the object pk in the view itself.

Comment: Bobby, you`re an angel. form.instance.id works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation the Built-in Views inherit from django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin class which requires the views it is mixed with to provide a self.object attribute.