# Django model won't update using .update()

Tags: python, django

I am trying to update a record in my database using info provided by my website's front-end using Model.objects.update(**kwargs) however on running the code I get the following error:

"'Record' with this Id already exists."

I would have expected that using the "update" method instead of the "create" method would mean that it shouldn't matter / should be expected that there is already a record with the same ID.

```py
def find_patient(request):
    my_form = ExampleForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        my_form = ExampleForm(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            UserInfo.objects.update(**my_form.cleaned_data)
        else:
            print(my_form.errors)
    context = {
        'form': my_form,
        'data_input': DataInput.objects,
        'sections': SECTION_CHOICES
    }
    return render(request, 'example.html', context)
```

The resulting error looks tike this:

id

User info with this Id already exists.

Am I misunderstanding the use case for "update" and if so, how would I go about using kwargs to update all fields for a given record in my db?

Comment: Your `update` aims to update *all* records, not just a single one. Since it includes the primary key, you thus aim to set all the `id`s to a specific value, which of course raises an error.

Comment: you are doing it wrong way please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673985/how-to-update-an-object-from-edit-form-in-django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UserInfo.objects.update(**my_form.cleaned_data)` aims to update *all* records in the database. Since your form includes a primary key (`id`), it will thus aim to update the `id` of all records to a given value. Since these values however should be unque, that means it will of course raise an error.

You can prevent that by filtering before the update, like:

```
UserInfo.objects.filter(
    pk=my_form.cleaned_data['id']
).update(**my_form.cleaned_data)
```

But updating a specific record is usually done differently: you usually pass the primary key in the URL. So the `urls.py` looks like:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path
from app.views import find_patient

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path('updatepatient/<int:pk>/', views.find_patient),
    # ...
]
```

Then in the view, we can pass the item to update to the form:

```
# app/views.py

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect

def find_patient(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(UserInfo, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        my_form = ExampleForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            my_form.save()
            return redirect('some-view-name')
    else:
        my_form = ExampleForm()
    context = {
        'form': my_form,
        'data_input': DataInput.objects.all(),
        'sections': SECTION_CHOICES
    }
    return render(request, 'example.html', context)
```

In case of a successful POST request, one usually redirects to a page. This is the well-known [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).