# How to edit an object using model form in django?

Tags: python, django

This may possibly be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24784867/11968044) answer. Currently, i'm working on updating an object using the same model form that is used to create the object.

my `views.py` looks like: (as from the answer):

```py
def newpost(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.save()
            return redirect('newpost')
    return render(request, 'console/newpost.html', {'form':form})

def editpost(request, pk):
    obj = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = PostForm(instance=obj)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.save()
            return redirect('editpost')
    return render(request, 'console/editpost.html', {'form':form})
```

And my html form in `editpost` looks like:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'newpost' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
</form>
```

and my `urls.py` looks like:

```py
path('console/post/', c_views.newpost, name='newpost'),
path('console/post/<int:pk>/', c_views.editpost, name='editpost'),
```

And the above codes works perfectly fine, but creates a new instance, with the data of the object taken from pk.

I added a `obj.delete()` code like this:

```py
def editpost(request, pk):
    obj = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = PostForm(instance=obj)
    obj.delete()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.save()
            return redirect('editpost')
    return render(request, 'console/editpost.html', {'form':form})
```

This code gives me the exact thing i wanted, but i know it's not a good practice. My question here is, is this a correct way or am i lagging somewhere.
I know the action in my `editpost` html should not be `{% url 'newpost' %}`, but if i use `{% url 'editpost' %}` i don't know how to pass the pk value inside the url tag. Can anyone suggest me the correct way?

Comment: why both edit view and delete view has same name?

Comment: Since i while updating the object, a new instance is created again with values that queried. So i deleted the previous object so that only the new object stays in the database!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your views should accept GET and POST methods, when the method is GET the form is instantiated with no `request.POST` data passed to it and the form is just rendered.

```
def newpost(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PostForm()
    else:  # POST
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('newpost')
    return render(request, 'console/newpost.html', {'form':form})

def editpost(request, pk):
    obj = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PostForm(instance=obj)
    else:  # POST
        form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('editpost')
    return render(request, 'console/editpost.html', {'form':form})

<form method="POST">
```

If you do not set the "action" attribute on a form it will submit the data to the same URL that the browser is currently on. This way you can use the same template for both views

Comment: Actually, by changing the `return redirect('editpost')` after the form is saved is where i went wrong. By changing the redirect url, it works fine with the previous code. However, the `action` tip you gave, reduced replicating the same template. Thank you so much!