# Issue updating Django database

Tags: python, django

Hi everyone please I'm having difficulty updating data from the database base list.
The editing page rendered but it doesn't show any input form.

Hi everyone please I'm having difficulty updating data from the database base list.
The editing page rendered but it doesn't show any input form.

Views.py

```
def edit_result(request, id): 
    instance = StudentResult.objects.filter().first()
    form = ResultModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return redirect('studentportal:student_detail')
          
    
          
    return render (request,'studentportal/edit_result.html', {'form':form })
```

Urls.py

```
path('edit_result/<int:id>', views.edit_result, name ="edit_result")
```

Models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfileInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='myuser')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=student_image, verbose_name="ProfilePicture", blank=True)
    level = models.IntegerField()
    guardian_email = models.EmailField()
    guardian_phone = models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        
        
        return reverse("studentportal:student_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.id}) 
  
class StudentResult(models.Model):
    
     student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='myresult')
     
     english = 'english'
     mathematic = 'mathematic'
     physic = 'physic'
     chemistry = 'chemistry'
     computer = 'computer'
     agric = 'agric'
     subject = [
        (english, 'english'),
        (mathematic, 'mathematic'),
        (physic, 'physic'),
        (chemistry, 'chemistry'),
        (computer, 'computer'),
        (agric, 'agric'),
        
     ]
     subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=subject)

     
    # subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     exam = models.IntegerField()
     test = models.IntegerField()
     total = models.IntegerField()
     
     def __str__(self):
         return self.subject
```

Forms.py

```
class StudentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('userprofile','first_name','last_name','profile_pic','level','guardian_email','guardian_phone')
        
        
class ResultModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StudentResult
        fields = ('student','subject','test','exam','total')
```

Temple html where the edit button link is

````
    {% for check in student.myresult.all %}
    <tr>
        
        <td>{{ check }}</td>
        <td>{{ check.test }}</td>
        <td>{{ check.exam }}</td>
        <td>{{ check.total }}</td>
        <td><div><a href="{% url 'studentportal:edit_result' student.id %}"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> </a>
        </div></td>
        <td><div><a href=" url 'studentportal:delete_result'  "><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </a>
        </div></td>
        
    </tr>
      {% endfor %}
</table>
        
</div>
    ```
**Error message**

DoesNotExist at /edit_result/1
StudentResult matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_result/1
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
StudentResult matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py, line 435, in get
Python Executable:  /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['/storage/emulated/0/schnew',
 '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python39.zip',
 '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9',
 '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 29 May 2021 17:19:42 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/storage/emulated/0/schnew/studentportal/views.py, line 127, in edit_result
    instance = StudentResult.objects.get(id=id) …
▶ Local vars
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py, line 85, in manager_method
                return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py, line 435, in get
            raise self.model.DoesNotExist( …
▶ Local vars

![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwVvM.png)
````

Comment: You need to pass the form in the context not the data.
Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673985/how-to-update-an-object-from-edit-form-in-django)

Comment: Thanks goku10, . I just changed modified the views.py    
 ```  
def edit_result(request, id):
  models = StudentResult
  form =ResultModelForm
  result = Student.objects.get(id = id)
  return render (request,'studentportal/edit_result.html', {'form':form }) 
 ```
  Now it shows all the inputs fields but they are empty

Comment: You need to pass the instance. Check the examples provided in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673985/how-to-update-an-object-from-edit-form-in-django) I have sent

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes but now I'm getting " StudentResult matching query does not exist"

Comment: While trying to modify the views, I noticed that. In my own case, I'm trying to update the data the StudentModel(which is a foreignkey to the Student model) and not the main model . 
So my views.py looks like this
```
def edit_result(request, id): 
    instance = StudentResult.objects.get(id=id)
    form = ResultModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return redirect('studentportal:student_detail')
          
          return direct_to_template(request, 'result_create.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Is it working or not?

Comment: It's Not working.  I'm getting " StudentResult matching query does not exist"

Comment: Update your code above. Also add the URLs

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: Why 3 return on same line? Also add you error details along with code.

Comment: I have done that. The third return was suppose to comment out

Comment: Try filter().first() instead of get().

Comment: I have done that ```  instance = StudentResult.objects.filter().first() ```   and I got this error ** ValueError at /edit_result/1
The view studentportal.views.edit_result didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: GET
base.py, line 30

Comment: Check your view function. Re-align return in your views.

Comment: Hi goku10. After the modification. Its now rendering the editing page thanks for helping me out. but there is this issue now that it renderes only the object on the list  that is``` http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_result/1``` irrespective of the one clicked, even if I clicked on the last one on the list it renderes the first one

Comment: You need to use .get(id=pk) for that.

Comment: Hi goku, please how can I go about passing student variable in the context as you earlier mentioned. Thanks

Comment: In your home page view function, pass the variable that you are going to use it in your template. The variable is a query.

Answer (score 0):

- you are trying to access a variable you haven't passed down to the template as context

Comment: Thanks Shrinidhi . Can you please help me on how to go about it. I'm still very new and I have tried all the possible way I know. Thanks

Comment: As you have used loop on the student but the student variable is not passed in the context. Or did you have another view function to render the context variable?

Comment: No, I don't have another view function to render the context variable. how can I do that please?