# What is wrong in if request.method == 'POST'

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Please what I am doing wrong in this function of Django ?

models.py

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', models.CASCADE, related_name='notifications')
    message = models.TextField('Повідомлення')
    viewed_at = models.DateTimeField('Проглянуто в', null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Створено', auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
```

views.py

```
class NotificationListView(core.ListView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    model = Notification
    template_name = 'auth/notifications.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user).annotate(
            viewed_at_null=ExpressionWrapper(
                Q(viewed_at__isnull=True),
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )).order_by('-created_at')

def notification_read(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        notification = get_object_or_404(Notification, pk=pk, viewed_at=None, user=request.user)
        form = NotificationForm(request.POST, instance=notification)
        if form.is_valid():
            notification.viewed_at = timezone.now()
            notification.save(update_fields=['viewed_at'])
            form.save()
            return redirect('users:notification')
```

urls.py

```
path('notification/', views.NotificationListView.as_view(), name='notification'),
    path('notification/<pk>/', views.notification_read, name='viewed-notification'),
```

template

```
<tbody>
    {% for item in object_list %}
      {% if item.viewed_at is None %}
        <tr>
          <td>
            {{ item.message }}
          <td>
          <td>
            {{ item.created_at }}
          <td>
            <form method="post"  action="{% url 'users:viewed-notification' item.pk %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
              <span class="badge badge-error">
                {{ form.viewed_at }}
                        <p><input type="submit" value="See it"/> 
           </p>
                </span>
            </form>

          </td>
        </tr>
      {% else %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

How can I do this better ? Can anybody can explain, why it does not working good?
My error that when I click this button all my data from ListPage does not work correctly!
It shows me no data in list! And when I enter on pk view it is show me error

UnboundLocalError at /users/notification/16/
local variable 'form' referenced before assignment

Comment: Please include the error message at least, and how you are calling the function in the first place to be sure request is actually a request

Comment: @EdoardoFacchinelli Updated my code!Please check it!

Comment: try "POST" instead of 'post'

Comment: It is does not work!How I understand - after this - form don not save new updated fields!(((

Comment: At least mention what is the error.

Comment: After push on a button See it!Form does not update field 'viewed_at'.The form does not save new data @Rasheedkotoor

Answer (score 1):

You need follow the documentation and declared a form variable in the function return:

```
return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'form': form})
```

look at this post:[How to update an object from edit form in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673985/how-to-update-an-object-from-edit-form-in-django)