# How to get database fields inside a form

Tags: python, django

What I need?
I need to put a form on my page, where all fields from my database are shown, and you can change them and save to database. A simple editor for my database table.

What I have?

my HTML:`enter code here`

```
<tr>
            <td>{{ form.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.token }}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-lg btn-success w-100">Add</button></td>
</tr>
```

my models.py

```
    from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class TrafficSources(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=250)
    token = models.CharField('token', max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my forms.py

```
from .models import TrafficSources
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput


class TrafficSourcesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TrafficSources

        fields = ['name', 'token']

        widgets = {
            'name': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': {{here I need the name from database table}}
            }),
            'token': TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': {{here I need the token from database table}}
            })
        }
```

This is the view.py for that page

```
def settings(request):
    ts = TrafficSources.objects.all()
    form = TrafficSourcesForm()
    data = {
        'form': form
    }
    url = 'url for API request'
#    
    ts_token = TrafficSources.objects.filter(name='propeller')
    for h in ts_token:
        token = h.token
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return render(request, 'mainpage/dashboard.html', {'ts': ts, 'js': res.text, 'hd': headers, 'form' : form})
```

My questions:
1)
I can put my database table on the HTML page.
I can create an empty working form (with the class)
BUT I can't do both in one place.
2)
If I want be able to save every field to the database ( separately) I need a a form in every row or I can do it from just a 1 form on a page?

For visualization I give you a screenshot how it should look like.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `instance` parameter for passing the object to the form to render it. You can try like this:

```
# view
def settings(request):
    ...
    forms = [TrafficSourcesForm(instance=x) for x in TrafficSources.objects.all()]
    return render(request, 'mainpage/dashboard.html', {'ts': ts, 'js': res.text, 'hd': headers, 'forms' : forms})

# template
{% for form in forms %}
<form action="/your-url/{{form.instance.id}}" method="post">
 {{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Comment: thanks, it's good for my 2nd question. but still have trouble how to get the data base  items at the moment where I create the form in the class

Comment: @mrdeath4 the form fields will contain information, that is how you can show the data

Comment: First things first: BIG thank you, its super bizarre but it WORKS. How is this magic working? How it knows I want the imput value take from the object? 2) Can I use that with not the whole form but with {{form.input}} only?

Comment: And can I send tha form.instance.ID via POST to make all actions on one URL?

Comment: I guess so. Then you need to get the object from request.POST.get('id') I guess.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by form.input

Comment: I use form.input to place my inputs where I want in my HTML. As I have many forms, when I click the submit button, I don't get the value from the correct form. How can I match the right form? where I can read the instance ID? its never written in my HTML

Comment: You can get instance id from {{form.instance.id}}

Comment: oh, thanks, now I can match everything except the inputs, how can I deal with them?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673985/how-to-update-an-object-from-edit-form-in-django, otherwise, please ask a new question. Thanks